# Copy Content of Folder from QProcess

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qprocess

I am trying to copy the content of a folder which contains files. which is need to copy the to dest path from src path but while copying it is not working as per the following steps pls let me know what could the best possible ways to copy the content of the folder to another

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
QMainWindow(parent),
ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
ui->setupUi(this);
qDebug() << QString("mv /home/praveen/fromTestImage/* /home/praveen/testImage/");
QString str1 = QString("cp /home/praveen/fromTestImage/* /home/praveen/testImage/");
QProcess::execute(str1);
}
```

Error :

```
cannot stat `/home/praveen/fromTestImage/*': No such file or directory
```

Thanks for your time !!
Praveen

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Wildcards](http://tldp.org/LDP/GNU-Linux-Tools-Summary/html/x11655.htm) like the `asterisk(*)` are not part of the `cp` command but the bash system so the executable `cp` will not recognize it, we can perform the same task without using that wildcard as shown in the following example:

```
QStringList args = QStringList()<<"-r" <<
                                  "/home/praveen/fromTestImage/."<<
                                  "/home/praveen/testImage/";

QProcess::execute("cp", args);
```

The solution was based on the following [response](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/180987)